# Multithreaded Matrix Multiplication C++

Tags: c++

I am writing Multithreaded Matrix Multiplication in C++ and calculating the result in row major order(one after another row).

I am diving the resultant rows calculations among the threads.
I pass as a parameter to thread the starting row number, where to start calculating resultant rows and a row Count i.e how many rows to calculate.
When I execute the code, I get some rows with zeroes instead of the product entries.
Here is the calculation code:

```
for(int i= arg->startingRow;i<arg->startingRow+ arg->rowCount;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<m2->cols;j++){
     result->data[j+ i*m2->cols] = 0;
     for(int k=0;k<m1->cols; k++){
        result->data[j+ i *m2->cols] += m1->data[k + i *m1->cols] * m2->data[j + k*m2->cols];
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: there is no any multithreading

Comment: Are you sure that your input is valid and fully initialized on the moment of multiplication?

Comment: @asmmo , this is the only part where I am calculating the product.
I thought, there might be an issue in this portion.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov , yes I give valid input.
I used cin for input and also read from the file.
But still get rows with zeroes

Comment: Probably, because you didn't show this code, problem is somewhere in multithreading code. Again probably, there is issues with threading synchronizations, as for example you reading results before thread is done calculating.

Comment: there are no enough comments to know what this snippet does and the meanings of the aparams. and I believe every part in the multiplication can be parallelized. see https://github.com/asmmo/MatMultiply/blob/master/source.cpp

Comment: @asmmo , I am basically doing strip decomposition on matrix.
In which divide the rows to each thread.